# Mocking IDocumentQuery in Unit Test that uses Linq queries

Tags: unit-testing, azure, asp.net-core, moq, azure-cosmosdb

I am writing unit tests for `DocumentDBRepository` but I got a null reference exception. I use Moq framework and XUnit.

Here's my methods in `DocumentDBRepository` class.

```cs
public class DocumentDBRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T: class
{
    private static string DatabaseId;
    private static string CollectionId;
    private static IDocumentClient client;
    public DocumentDBRepository(IDocumentClient documentClient, string databaseId, string collectionId)
    {
        DatabaseId = databaseId;
        CollectionId = collectionId;
        client = documentClient;
        CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
        CreateCollectionIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
    }

    public async Task<IDocumentQuery<T>> GetQuery(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        try
        {
            IDocumentQuery<T> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
          UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId),
          new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true })
          .Where(predicate)
          .AsDocumentQuery();

            return query;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw;
        }    
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetEntities(IDocumentQuery<T> query)
    {
        try
        {
            List<T> results = new List<T>();
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>());
            }

            return results;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }            
    }
}
```

Here's my test code:

```cs
public interface IFakeDocumentQuery<T> : IDocumentQuery<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>
{

}

[Fact]
public async virtual Task Test_GetBooksById()
{

    var expected = new List<Book> {
        new Book { ID = "123", Description = "HarryPotter"},
        new Book { ID = "124", Description = "HarryPotter2"} };


    var response = new FeedResponse<Book>(expected);

    var mockDocumentQuery = new Mock<IFakeDocumentQuery<Book>>();

    mockDocumentQuery.SetupSequence(_ => _.HasMoreResults)
                     .Returns(true)
                     .Returns(false);

    mockDocumentQuery.Setup(_ => _.ExecuteNextAsync<Book>(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
                     .ReturnsAsync(response);

    var client = new Mock<IDocumentClient>();

    client.Setup(_ => _.CreateDocumentQuery<Book>(It.IsAny<Uri>(), It.IsAny<FeedOptions>()))
          .Returns(mockDocumentQuery.Object);

    var documentsRepository = new DocumentDBRepository<Book>(client.Object, "123", "123");

    //Act
    var query = await documentsRepository.GetQuery(t => t != null);
    var entities = await documentsRepository.GetEntities(query);

    //Assert
    if (entities != null)
    {
        entities.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
    }
}
```

Here's the error message after running the test method:

> Message: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object.

When I stepped through the code, the error happens right after the the test code called `GetQuery()` method:

```cs
 IDocumentQuery<T> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
              UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId),
              new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true })
              .Where(predicate)
              .AsDocumentQuery();
```

Here's my thought process: when I stepped through the entire code, I do not see any null variables. But in the 'response' variable from the second line of the test method, it does show a lot of the properties are null exception but result view shows the 'expected' variable.

My question is, is it because of the response variable that caused the null reference exception? Or somewhere else?

PS: Test code reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48349659/how-to-should-i-mock-documentclient-for-documentdb-unit-testing?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I also tried turning on the Mock behavior to strict and saw this error message.

> Message: System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred.
>   (IDocumentClient.ReadDatabaseAsync(dbs/123, null) invocation failed
>   with mock behavior Strict. All invocations on the mock must have a
>   corresponding setup.)
>   ---- Moq.MockException : IDocumentClient.ReadDatabaseAsync(dbs/123, null) invocation failed with mock behavior Strict. All invocations on
>   the mock must have a corresponding setup.

Comment: It is most likely because of `.Where(predicate)` but that is just from my initial look at what you provided. Have not had the time to give it a proper review as yet.

Comment: Provide the constructor for `DocumentDBRepository` so that a [mcve] can be done to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look. But would be greatly appreciate if you could review :)

Comment: You are trying to Setup `CreateDocumentQuery` to return `IDocumentQuery` but it actually returns `IOrderedQueryable`. That means that yout mock setup won't match and it will return null on the object. It will only return `IDocumentQuery` once you do cast it with `AsDocumentQuery`. It works on that other example because there is no where clause.

Comment: @Elfocrash I changed from `client.Setup(_ => _.CreateDocumentQuery<Book>(It.IsAny<Uri>(), It.IsAny<FeedOptions>()))
                  .Returns(mockDocumentQuery.Object);` to  `client.Setup(_ => _.CreateDocumentQuery<Book>(It.IsAny<Uri>(), It.IsAny<FeedOptions>()).AsDocumentQuery())
                  .Returns(mockDocumentQuery.Object);` The program stops right after this line and the error shows `Message: System.NotSupportedException : Invalid setup on an extension method: _ => _.CreateDocumentQuery<Book>(It.IsAny<Uri>(), It.IsAny<FeedOptions>()).AsDocumentQuery<Book>()`

Comment: @Elfocrash But I do understand and agree with your reasoning.

Comment: @WendyWang This wouldn't work. It's not valid mock setup. You need to keep the setup part the same but change your return to something that implements `IOrderedQueryable`.

Comment: As suspected the problem is `.Where`. Ran a test with your example and removed the `.Where` and it executes to completion. The fake interface inherits from both `IOrderedQueryable` and `IDocumentQuery`. The issue is that the `Where` is converting it back to a plain `IEnumerable` and the `AsDocumentQuery` is crapping out as it is expecting an `IDocumentQuery` . Investigating now.

Comment: @Nkosi Yes I can confirm on my end that removing `Where` make the test passed..

Comment: @Nkosi Could you please show me an example with code for how to fix it? Or would it make sense to do unit testing on local document DB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suspected the problem is `.Where(predicate)`. I ran a test with the provided example and removed the `.Where` clause and it executed to completion.

The fake interface inherits from both `IOrderedQueryable` and `IDocumentQuery`. The issue is that the `Where` is converting it back to a plain `IEnumerable` because of the `List` data source and the `AsDocumentQuery` is crapping out as it is expecting an `IDocumentQuery`

I am not a fan of tightly coupling to APIs I can't control. I would abstract my way around such implementation details for that very reason.

The work around involved having to provide a fake Linq `IQueryProvider` to bypass any queries and return a type that derives from `IDocumentQuery` so as to allow `AsDocumentQuery` to behave as intended.

But first I refactored `GetEntities` and made `GetQuery` private to stop the repository from being a leaky abstraction.

```cs
private IDocumentQuery<T> getQuery(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) {
    var uri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId);
    var feedOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true };
    var queryable = client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(uri, feedOptions);
    IQueryable<T> filter = queryable.Where(predicate);
    IDocumentQuery<T> query = filter.AsDocumentQuery();
    return query;
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetEntities(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) {
    try {
        IDocumentQuery<T> query = getQuery(predicate);
        var results = new List<T>();
        while (query.HasMoreResults) {
            results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>());
        }
        return results;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Note that `getQuery` is not doing anything async so it should not be returning a `Task<>` anyway.

Next in the test the mocked `IDocumentQuery` was set up to allow the test to flow to completion. This was done by providing a mocked `IQueryProvider` the would return the mocked `IDocumentQuery` when Linq queries are invoked against it. *(which was the cause of the problem to begin with)*

```cs
public async virtual Task Test_GetBooksById() {
    //Arrange
    var id = "123";
    Expression<Func<Book, bool>> predicate = t => t.ID == id;
    var dataSource = new List<Book> {
        new Book { ID = id, Description = "HarryPotter"},
        new Book { ID = "124", Description = "HarryPotter2"} 
    }.AsQueryable();

    var expected = dataSource.Where(predicate);

    var response = new FeedResponse<Book>(expected);

    var mockDocumentQuery = new Mock<IFakeDocumentQuery<Book>>();

    mockDocumentQuery
        .SetupSequence(_ => _.HasMoreResults)
        .Returns(true)
        .Returns(false);

    mockDocumentQuery
        .Setup(_ => _.ExecuteNextAsync<Book>(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(response);

    var provider = new Mock<IQueryProvider>();
    provider
        .Setup(_ => _.CreateQuery<Book>(It.IsAny<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>()))
        .Returns((Expression expression) => {                
            if (expression != null) {
                dataSource = dataSource.Provider.CreateQuery<Book>(expression);
            }
            mockDocumentQuery.Object;
        });

    mockDocumentQuery.As<IQueryable<Book>>().Setup(x => x.Provider).Returns(provider.Object);
    mockDocumentQuery.As<IQueryable<Book>>().Setup(x => x.Expression).Returns(() => dataSource.Expression);
    mockDocumentQuery.As<IQueryable<Book>>().Setup(x => x.ElementType).Returns(() => dataSource.ElementType);
    mockDocumentQuery.As<IQueryable<Book>>().Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => dataSource.GetEnumerator());

    var client = new Mock<IDocumentClient>();

    client.Setup(_ => _.CreateDocumentQuery<Book>(It.IsAny<Uri>(), It.IsAny<FeedOptions>()))
          .Returns(mockDocumentQuery.Object);

    var documentsRepository = new DocumentDBRepository<Book>(client.Object, "123", "123");

    //Act
    var entities = await documentsRepository.GetEntities(predicate);

    //Assert
    entities.Should()
        .NotBeNullOrEmpty()
        .And.BeEquivalentTo(expected);
}
```

This allowed the test to be exercised to completion, behave as expected, and pass the test.

Comment: I'm facing similar situation and after studying this code I'm wondering if there is much (any?) merit in this test, considering that almost everything has been mocked. `GetEntities` and `getQuery` have no business rules. So, at the end, what exactly has been tested? Thanks!