# Mocking IDocumentQuery in Unit Test that uses SQL Queries

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure, moq, azure-cosmosdb

I am using unit tests to test `DocumentDBRepository` class. I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906029/mocking-idocumentquery-in-unit-test-that-uses-linq-queries) as an example for the SQL queries use case. But it shows error of

> Message: System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery
>   to type
>   'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.IDocumentQuery

Here's my code for `DocumentDBRepository` class

```
private IDocumentQuery<T> GetQueryBySQL(string queryStr)
{
    var uri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_databaseId, _collectionId);
    var feedOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true };
    IQueryable<T> filter = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(uri, queryStr, feedOptions); 
    IDocumentQuery<T> query = filter.AsDocumentQuery();
    return query;

}

public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> RunQueryAsync(string queryString)
{
    IDocumentQuery<T> query = GetQueryBySQL(queryString);

    List<T> results = new List<T>();

    while (query.HasMoreResults)
    {
        results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>());
    }
    return results;
}
```

Here's my code for my test class

```
public async virtual Task Test_GetEntitiesAsyncBySQL()
{
    var id = "100";
    string queryString = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.ID = " + id;
    var dataSource = new List<Book> {
            new Book { ID = "100", Title = "abc"}}.AsQueryable();


    Expression<Func<Book, bool>> predicate = t => t.ID == id;
    var expected = dataSource.Where(predicate.Compile());
    var response = new FeedResponse<Book>(expected);

    var mockDocumentQuery = new Mock<DocumentDBRepositoryTest.IFakeDocumentQuery<Book>>();

    mockDocumentQuery
        .SetupSequence(_ => _.HasMoreResults)
        .Returns(true)
        .Returns(false);

    mockDocumentQuery
        .Setup(_ => _.ExecuteNextAsync<Book>(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(response);

    var provider = new Mock<IQueryProvider>();
    provider
        .Setup(_ => _.CreateQuery<Book>(It.IsAny<Expression>()))
        .Returns(mockDocumentQuery.Object);

    mockDocumentQuery.As<IQueryable<Book>>().Setup(x => x.Provider).Returns(provider.Object);
    mockDocumentQuery.As<IQueryable<Book>>().Setup(x => x.Expression).Returns(dataSource.Expression);
    mockDocumentQuery.As<IQueryable<Book>>().Setup(x => x.ElementType).Returns(dataSource.ElementType);
    mockDocumentQuery.As<IQueryable<Book>>().Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => dataSource.GetEnumerator());

    var client = new Mock<IDocumentClient>();

    client.Setup(_ => _.CreateDocumentQuery<Book>(It.IsAny<Uri>(), It.IsAny<FeedOptions>()))
          .Returns(mockDocumentQuery.Object);

    var documentsRepository = new DocumentDBRepository<Book>(client.Object, "100", "100");

    //Act
    var entities = await documentsRepository.RunQueryAsync(queryString);

    //Assert
    entities.Should()
        .NotBeNullOrEmpty()
        .And.BeEquivalentTo(expected);
}
```

The break point stops at this line of code:

```
IQueryable<T> filter = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(uri, queryStr, feedOptions);
```

The `filter` variable shows null exception at a lot of its properties and result view shows empty, when it's supposed to show the `expected` value that I defined in the test method.

Any clue how to fix it?

Comment: You have to setup the `CreateDocumentQuery` overload that expects a query string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct `CreateDocumentQuery` overload needs to be set up on the mocked client.

The method under test uses

```
IQueryable<T> filter = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(uri, queryStr, feedOptions);
```

Yet in arranging the test, the client was set up like

```
client
    .Setup(_ => _.CreateDocumentQuery<Book>(It.IsAny<Uri>(), It.IsAny<FeedOptions>()))
    .Returns(mockDocumentQuery.Object);
```

That should be changed to

```
client
    .Setup(_ => _.CreateDocumentQuery<Book>(It.IsAny<Uri>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<FeedOptions>()))
    .Returns(mockDocumentQuery.Object);
```

Because of the additional `queryStr` parameter. It could have also used the string parameter directly as an alternative, given that is is being explicitly injected into the method and can be used as part of the expectation.

```
client
    .Setup(_ => _.CreateDocumentQuery<Book>(It.IsAny<Uri>(), queryStr, It.IsAny<FeedOptions>()))
    .Returns(mockDocumentQuery.Object);
```

Since the method under test is not using Linq directly when building the query then there is no need to mock/override the query provider as was in a previous iteration of this topic

Here is the completed test after the above changes

```
public async virtual Task Test_GetEntitiesAsyncBySQL() {
    //Arrange
    var id = "100";
    string queryString = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.ID = " + id;
    var dataSource = new List<Book> {
        new Book { ID = "100", Title = "abc"}
    }.AsQueryable();

    Expression<Func<Book, bool>> predicate = t => t.ID == id;
    var expected = dataSource.Where(predicate.Compile());
    var response = new FeedResponse<Book>(expected);

    var mockDocumentQuery = new Mock<IFakeDocumentQuery<Book>>();

    mockDocumentQuery
        .SetupSequence(_ => _.HasMoreResults)
        .Returns(true)
        .Returns(false);

    mockDocumentQuery
        .Setup(_ => _.ExecuteNextAsync<Book>(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(response);

    //Note the change here
    mockDocumentQuery.As<IQueryable<Book>>().Setup(_ => _.Provider).Returns(dataSource.Provider);
    mockDocumentQuery.As<IQueryable<Book>>().Setup(_ => _.Expression).Returns(dataSource.Expression);
    mockDocumentQuery.As<IQueryable<Book>>().Setup(_ => _.ElementType).Returns(dataSource.ElementType);
    mockDocumentQuery.As<IQueryable<Book>>().Setup(_ => _.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => dataSource.GetEnumerator());

    var client = new Mock<IDocumentClient>();

    //Note the change here
    client
        .Setup(_ => _.CreateDocumentQuery<Book>(It.IsAny<Uri>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<FeedOptions>()))
        .Returns(mockDocumentQuery.Object);

    var documentsRepository = new DocumentDBRepository<Book>(client.Object, "100", "100");

    //Act
    var entities = await documentsRepository.RunQueryAsync(queryString);

    //Assert
    entities.Should()
        .NotBeNullOrEmpty()
        .And.BeEquivalentTo(expected);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see the error seems quite simple to me.

Here is how you set up the parameters list -

```
client.Setup(_ => _.CreateDocumentQuery<Book>(It.IsAny<Uri>(), It.IsAny<FeedOptions>()))
      .Returns(mockDocumentQuery.Object);
```

And here is how you call CreateDocumentQuery -

```
IQueryable<T> filter = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(uri, queryStr, feedOptions);
```

So basically **you've missed queryString**. Here is what you should do -

```
client.Setup(_ => _.CreateDocumentQuery<Book>(It.IsAny<Uri>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<FeedOptions>()))
              .Returns(mockDocumentQuery.Object);
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the solution suggested by **Nkosi** doesn't work for me (even tho, logically it seems correct). Please notice the difference in the `IQueryProvider` mock that interacts with the `IEnumerable` that we expect as the result of the query.

```
    // somewhere in your test class
    public interface IFakeDocumentQuery<T> : IDocumentQuery<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>
    {
    }

    // somewhere in your test method
    var expected = new List<YourType>
    {
        new YourType
        {
            yourField = "yourValue"
        }
    };

    var mockDocumentClient = new Mock<IDocumentClient>();
    var dataSource = expected.AsQueryable();
    var response = new FeedResponse<YourType>(dataSource);
    var mockDocumentQuery = new Mock<IFakeDocumentQuery<YourType>>();

    // the part that gets the work done :)
    var provider = new Mock<IQueryProvider>();
    provider
        .Setup(p => p.CreateQuery<YourType>(It.IsAny<Expression>()))
        .Returns(mockDocumentQuery.Object);
    mockDocumentQuery
        .Setup(q => q.ExecuteNextAsync<YourType>(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(response);
    mockDocumentQuery
        .SetupSequence(q => q.HasMoreResults)
        .Returns(true)
        .Returns(false);
    mockDocumentQuery
        .As<IQueryable<YourType>>()
        .Setup(x => x.Provider)
        .Returns(provider.Object);
    mockDocumentQuery
        .As<IQueryable<YourType>>()
        .Setup(x => x.Expression)
        .Returns(dataSource.Expression);
    mockDocumentQuery
        .As<IQueryable<YourType>>()
        .Setup(x => x.ElementType)
        .Returns(dataSource.ElementType);
    mockDocumentQuery
        .As<IQueryable<YourType>>()
        .Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator())
        .Returns(dataSource.GetEnumerator);
    mockDocumentClient
        .Setup(c => c.CreateDocumentQuery<YourType>(It.IsAny<Uri>(), It.IsAny<FeedOptions>()))
        .Returns(mockDocumentQuery.Object);
```