# Constructor arguments cannot be passed for interface mocks (Mock IFeedResponse)

Tags: c#, azure, unit-testing, moq, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to write unit tests for `DocumentDBRepository` paging code. Since there is continuation token involved in the `FeedResponse`, I need to mock the `FeedResponse` in order to put some value for `FeedResponse.ContinuationToken`. But the problem is that I got an error saying:

> Message: System.ArgumentException : Constructor arguments cannot be
>   passed for interface mocks.

Does it mean I am not able to mock `FeedResponse`? Or maybe the way I use `FeedResponse` is wrong?

Here's my code:

```
var response = new Mock<IFeedResponse<T>>(expected);
response.Setup(_ => _.ResponseContinuation).Returns(It.IsAny<string>());
var mockDocumentQuery = new Mock<IFakeDocumentQuery<T>>();

mockDocumentQuery
    .SetupSequence(_ => _.HasMoreResults)
    .Returns(true)
    .Returns(false);

mockDocumentQuery
    .Setup(_ => _.ExecuteNextAsync<T>(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .Returns((Task<FeedResponse<T>>)response.Object);
```

When I debugged, the break point stops at  `var response = new Mock<IFeedResponse<T>>(expected);` and then the error happened.

Comment: You are mocking interface so you don't need to pass the constructor arguments of class while creating mock. You simply need to do `var response = new Mock<IFeedResponse<T>>();`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya hmm, since the `expected` is the expected return value from CosmosDB, then where do I pass this value?

Comment: You need to set this as a return value when you arrange expectations for the mock.

Comment: @WendyW. You can use an actual instance of `FeedResponse`. no need to mock it. Similar to one of the answers I gave to one of our earlier questions here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49911733/5233410

Comment: @Nkosi I did try that but since i have FeedResponse.ContinuationToken, it broke the unit tests.. So I have to figure out how to put the value for the token for the feed response in the tests..

Comment: Ok that makes sense. thing is you were mocking the interface and trying to pass a constructor argument. That wont work. check to see if the class has the member you want to mock as virtual. or if you can set it manually.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I see.. but do you know which property of the `FeedResponse` should I assign to for the expected value returned from CosmosDB?

Comment: I have no knowledge about cosmosdb and how to write code for that. Can you share the code which you are trying to unit test? I will be able to suggest how to use mock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because you were mocking the interface and trying to pass a constructor argument. That wont work as stated by the error message.

You can however use an actual instance of `FeedResponse`.

Given that the desired member is not `virtual` and is also read-only, you could consider stubbing the class and overriding the default behavior since `FeedResponse<T>` is not `sealed`.

For example

```
public class FeedResponseStub<T> : FeedResponse<T> {
    private string token;

    public FeedResponseStub(IEnumerable<T> result, string token)
        : base(result) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public new string ResponseContinuation {
        get {
            return token;
        }
    }
}
```

and using the stub in the test

```
//...

var token = ".....";
var response = new FeedResponseStub<T>(expected, token);

//...

mockDocumentQuery
    .Setup(_ => _.ExecuteNextAsync<T>(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(response);

//...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way I work around it in [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut/blob/develop/src/Cosmonaut/Testing/TestingExtensions.cs#L44).

```
public static FeedResponse<T> ToFeedResponse<T>(this IQueryable<T> resource, IDictionary<string, string> responseHeaders = null)
    {
        var feedResponseType = Type.GetType("Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.FeedResponse`1, Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core, Version=1.9.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35");

        var flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;

        var headers = new NameValueCollection
        {
            { "x-ms-request-charge", "0" },
            { "x-ms-activity-id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString() }
        };

        if (responseHeaders != null)
        {
            foreach (var responseHeader in responseHeaders)
            {
                headers[responseHeader.Key] = responseHeader.Value;
            }
        }

        var arguments = new object[] { resource, resource.Count(), headers, false, null };

        if (feedResponseType != null)
        {
            var t = feedResponseType.MakeGenericType(typeof(T));

            var feedResponse = Activator.CreateInstance(t, flags, null, arguments, null);

            return (FeedResponse<T>)feedResponse;
        }

        return new FeedResponse<T>();
    }
}
```

You can pass your continuation token as a header key-value in the dictionary to set the FeedResponse value.
You can do that by setting the `x-ms-continuation` value to a token.

Keep in mind that the `ResponseContinuation` property of the `FeedResponse` also takes the `useETagAsContinuation` value into account. I default it to false in the reflection invoked constructor.

For any further reference check the project's code and how unit tests are written.